# how to "angular $scope function" with "factory"

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I want to angular controller passing parameters(`$scope`)

but `$scope.setName = function()` is not work,

how can I do.. please~

script

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
  return {
    name: "Ting"
  }
});
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.setName = function() {
    Data.name = "Jack";
  }
});
myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.setName = function() {
    Data.name = "Moby";
  }
});
```

html

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.name"/>
      <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      {{person.name}}
      <button ng-click="setName()">set name to jack</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      {{person.name}}
      <button ng-click="setName()">set name to jack</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you elaborate `$scope.setName = function() is not working`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working fine.

You are printing model instead of service.

As service is a singleton changing in on controller it'll change for every controller which is alive

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
  return {
    name: "Ting"
  }
});
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.setName = function() {
    Data.name = "Jack";
  }
});
myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
  $scope.data = Data;

  $scope.setName = function() {
    Data.name = "Moby";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.name"/>
      <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
      {{data.name}}
      <button ng-click="setName()">set name to jack</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
      {{data.name}}
      <button ng-click="setName()">set name to jack</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```